# Cakephp 3 Can't catch FatalErrorException

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a function inside of a Component to send contact mail using Gmail. For whatever reason my work network is blocking the secure connection to Gmail if i use my phone internet for example it works fine so it's clear that the email configuration is fine. What i'm really interested is in catching that FatalErrorException so i can return false to the controller and show an error message in the web site but i'm failing to do so.

This is my code of the component:

```
try{
  $correo = new Email();
  $correo
    ->transport('mail')              
    ->template('contacto_negocio')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to($correoPara)
    ->from($correoDe, $nombreDe)
    ->replyTo($correoDe, $nombreDe)
    ->subject(__('Mensaje de contacto desde ').$sitio_nombre_secundario)
    ->viewVars([
      'sitio_nombre_secundario'=>$sitio_nombre_secundario,          
      'sitio_nombre' => $sitio_nombre,
      'nombreDe'=>$nombreDe,
      'correoDe'=>$correoDe,
      'mensaje'=>$mensaje
    ])        
    ->send();

} catch (FatalErrorException $ex){  
  return false;

} catch(SocketException $ex){   
  return false;

}catch (\Exception $ex) {
  return false;
}
```

And the code in the controller:

```
if($this->Correo->contactoNegocio($correo, $nombreDe, $correoDe, $mensaje)){
  $respuesta = ['cod'=>1, 'mensaje'=>'Message sent'];                
}else{
  $respuesta = ['cod'=>0, 'mensaje'=>'<span style="color:red; font-size: 12px;">Message not sent.<span>'];
}
```

[image]

What i am missing??

Comment: Your code does not reach the point that it can catch `FatalErrorException` because the execution time error is more or less the result of a shutdown function that cake handles on its own. To my knowledge you can increase the limit or try to modify their shutdown method, but you won't be able to "catch" this as an exception.

Comment: The error is indicating that your script is timing out. To @skrilled's point, it is never reaching the `catch` block because it has already stopped execution before that.

Comment: You are both right, i couldn't see that. I set the max_execution_time to 60 second and also set a timeout of 30 seconds to the configTransport and that solve my problem.

Thank you both for replying.

Comment: @skrilled please turn your comment into an answer so that this question doesn't show any longer in the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: @InigoFlores done :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not reach the point that it can catch `FatalErrorException` because the execution time error is more or less the result of a shutdown function that cake handles on its own.

You can increase the limit or try to modify their shutdown method, but you won't be able to "catch" this as an exception as it stops execution before the catch block.